# Why Swagger is invalidating types long, boolean and object on my specs?

Tags: python, flask, yaml, swagger, swagger-ui

I created an extension to make Flask-Views Swaggable, this is very simple, you put some YAML definition on some file or in docstring and Flasgger takes care of creating API specs and expose Swagger UI.

Github: https://github.com/rochacbruno/flasgger
Example APP: http://flasgger-rochacbruno.rhcloud.com/apidocs/index.html?url=/v2/spec

Now I got a problem here:

http://online.swagger.io/validator/debug?url=http://flasgger-rochacbruno.rhcloud.com/v2/spec

[image]

The swagger validator says my specs are invalid, but everything is working well, why is this saying my definitions are invalid?

Anwers can come as contribution to the github repo (that example app is there)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue is that your `candidate_id` under the `req_query` model has a `required` property. While the property is allowed, the value type is wrong and irrelevant in this case (that's not how you use it). Since at the `req_query` level you've mentioned that `candidate_id` is `required` in the array, you just need to drop it from the property definition.

The second issue is that `long` is not a valid type. If you take a look at https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#data-types, you'll see that `long` translates to `type` being `integer` and `format` being `int64`.

Comment: There was another 2 problems, dateTime is not a valid format, I used string with format date-time, and also #ref has no schema. Thanks